# snippet generation in php

Tags: php, full-text-search, code-snippets

I have a long chunk of text that came back from a search query.
I'd like to display a snippet of the text, not the entire thing, and highlight the search query within the snippet.
I realize that decided what part of the text to slice can be complicated, and I was hoping for any ideas on how do to this?

Thanks!

Comment: Are there any HTML characters or it is plain text?

Comment: *(related)* http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=highlight+text+php

Answer (score 1):

for example

```
$text = "
I have a long chunk of text that came back from a search query. I'd like to display a
snippet of the text, not the entire thing, and highlight the search query within the
snippet. I realize that decided what part of the text to slice can be complicated, and
I was hoping for any ideas on how do to this?
";

$query = "the text";

preg_match("~\b.{0,20}$query.{0,20}\b~", $text, $m);
echo str_replace($query, "<strong>$query</strong>", $m[0]);
```